# prevent outlook from deleting recurring event

Tags: outlook, appointment

I have a plugin which syncs read-only shared calendars in Outlook with our collaboration system. I need to make sure the user cannot delete any appointments in these read-only calendars. It's possible to attach an event handler to any appointment in Outlook (this works) but it won't work for recurring events. Each occurrence in the recurrence pattern is a separate object in Outlook, and the app must attach an event handler to each of such objects. If the recurrence pattern is endless (which is quite popular for such appointments), the app should attach infinite number of event handlers.

Is it possible to attach an event handler to some of kind of a grouping object (if such entity exists) for all occurrences at once, or is there any other method of solving my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an instance of a recurring appointment is deleted, the master appointment will be modified. You can intercept that change by subscribing to the AppointmentItem.Write event, whcih has the Cancel parameter.

Comment: I checked with the developer. Actually, this was the first thing we tried (subscribing to AppointmentItem.Write of the master appointment). It simply does not get fired in case of deleting an instance within recurrence pattern..

Comment: Does BeforeDelete event fire?

Comment: No, with our tests it only fires when the master appointment itself gets deleted, not any recurrence belonging to it.

Comment: I can see it firing on the recurrence instance being deleted. Does it work for you? Can you see it in OutlookSpy if you select the instance, click the Item button, go to the Events tab, then delete the instance?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it fires for a recurrence instance. But as the recurrence can be infinite, I would need to subscribe to infinite number of recurrences to track them all. That's obviously not possible.

Comment: To delete a particular instance, it needs to be selected first. You can track the selected items using the Explorer.Selection collection and the Explorer.SelectionChange event.